# Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "bemerken" und "merken"?

Tags: difference

Beide Verben bedeuten im Englischen *"to notice"*, sagte mir mein Wörterbuch. Aber gibt es doch irgendeinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden?

Außerdem: *"unnoticed"* heißt auf Deutsch *"un**b**emerkt"*. Warum ist es nicht *"un**g**emerkt"*?

Comment: Danke für Korrigieren! Wenn doch ich eine Frage ohne Fehler stellen könnte.

Comment: Du hättest dann wahrscheinlich keine Fragen mehr ;)

Comment: Haha. Ich hoffe, die Fragen nie auf hören. Aber hoffe ich sicherlich dass ihre Qualität zeitlich verbessert. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Merken* hat laut Duden unter anderem die Bedeutungen:

> 1. (etwas, was nicht ohne Weiteres erkennbar ist) durch Sinneswahrnehmung und Beobachtung oder durch Eingebung, ahnendes Gefühl erkennen, bemerken, spüren
> 2. im Gedächtnis behalten

Die erste Bedeutung davon würde man mit „to notice“ übersetzen, die zweite mit „to keep in mind“.

*Bemerken* hat unter anderem die Bedeutungen:

> 1. wahrnehmen, entdecken, erkennen
> 2. äußern, [kurz] sagen, einwerfen

Die erste Bedeutung würde man ebenfalls mit „to notice“ übersetzen, die zweite beispielsweise mit „to interpose“.

Den Unterschied zwischen merken und bemerken zu finden, ist manchmal nicht so einfach. Häufig haben beide die gleiche Bedeutung.

Ich würde bspw. sagen:

> Er bemerkte ihre neue Frisur.

Nicht aber:

> Er merkte ihre neue Frisur.

Korrekt, aber mit unterschiedlichen Bedeutungen:

> Ich bemerkte die Katze. (Ich sah oder hörte sie.)
>
> Ich merkte die Katze. (Sie lief um meine Beine.)

Aus meiner Sicht gleiche Bedeutungen:

> Ich merkte, dass ich etwas falsch gemacht hatte.
>
> Ich bemerkte, dass ich etwas falsch gemacht hatte.

Comment: Bei der Katze, die die Beine berührt würde merken dann aber mit to feel übersetzt, wobei der Kontext des Satzes in dem fall nur durch den Kommentar hergestellt wird, ansonste auch Falsch, bzw. unvollständig

Comment: Schöne Antwort. "Er merkte die Katze" würde ich allerdings nicht sagen, sondern "er spürte, dass sie ihm um die Beine lief".