# Usage of "realisieren", "merken" and "bemerken"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between *realisieren*, *merken* and *bemerken*?

> Als ich im Park spazierenging, realisierte/merkte/bermerkte ich, dass die Sonne unterging.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen "bemerken" und "merken"?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6083/gibt-es-einen-unterschied-zwischen-bemerken-und-merken)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can use all of them. You use *realisieren* when you suddenly notice someting although it was there before. *merken/bemerken* is more like watch something happening.
One thing to edit: if you use *als*, realizing something appears to be a consequence. In this case, you may better use *während* (during).

Answer (score 6):

1. **merken**: to feel something, to notice something or someone
2. **bemerken**: to notice a change of the current situation
3. **realisieren**: understanding a fact

So all of them can be used, personally I'd go for **bemerkte**.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the meanings of "realisieren" posted in the other two answers are based on the English meaning of it. The actual German meaning of "realisiern" is "to make something come true".

Comment: I agree, that this is the more traditional meaning of *realisieren*, but the anglizism of taking over the meaning meaning of *realize* has found such widespread use, that it can be considered as valid as well, see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/realisieren), meaning 2.