# bemerken vs merken

Tags: word-usage, english-to-german, single-word-request, vocabulary

Which one is the correct translation for "I suddenly realised that the bus was there in 7 minutes":

1. Ich habe plötzlich gemerkt, dass der Bus in 7 Minuten wäre.
2. Ich habe plötzlich bemerkt, dass der Bus in 7 Minuten wäre.

I would be happy for an explanation, thanks in advance.

Note: I have some understanding of the verbs already but am struggling more with this specific example.

Comment: Do you mean *was **there** in 7 minutes* ?

Comment: Maybe I can try to make what I meant in the first place more obvious: I had realised that the bus was/would be there in 7 minutes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of "realisieren", "merken" and "bemerken"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9167/usage-of-realisieren-merken-and-bemerken)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have some understanding of the verbs already but was struggling more with this specific example.

Answer (score 2):

Both *gemerkt* and *bemerkt* are okay in that context. The difference is subtle. *Bemerken* is more random that *merken*.

But it must be

> Ich habe plötzlich gemerkt/bemerkt, dass der Bus in 7 Minuten **da** **ist**.

You need the *da*. And German speakers don't use Konjunktiv II in such constructions as the bus is going to be there in seven minutes **for real**. You may also want to reorder, and add a *schon* to focus on the urgency.

> Ich habe plötzlich gemerkt/bemerkt, dass schon in 7 Minuten der Bus da ist.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! My main question is answered which was about merken/bemerken. If I want to say everything in past tense, can I say: "Ich habe/hatte plötlizch gemerkt/bemerkt, dass der Bus schon in 7 Minuten da war."  ?

Comment: While I agree based on my experience as a German native speaker with the statement "*And German speakers don't use Konjunktiv II in such constructions as the bus is going to be there in seven minutes for real.*", I would like to add, that using *da* with Konjunktiv II is not wrong to say but seldom to hear.

Comment: and is my above sentence correct with "war". or how can I say it otherwise? @Olafant

Comment: I think the right translation for "the bus is in X minutes" is "der Bus fährt in X Minuten ab/los/weg". When it arrives doesn't matter after all, only when it leaves.

Comment: what I mean is that the whole thing was in the past. Like I suddenly realised last Friday that the bus (of last Friday) was after 10 minutes

Comment: Perfekt marks the past already. If you want to mark it as a story on top, use *hatte* and *war* indeed. That's the past and the non-past inside a story. That the story in its entirety also plays in the past has to be guessed from context.

Answer (score 2):

Which one can be considered correct depends on the intended meaning of

> realized

Both sentences have the same structure:

*haben* + adverb + verb in *Partizip II*

That structure sets the whole action in *Perfekt*.

The difference in meaning is the result of the fact, that two different verbs are used.

1. **merken**

*gemerkt* is Part. II of the verb [**merken**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/merken) and means something along the lines

> perceiving something emotionally, observingly, noticing something

2. **bemerken**

*Partizip II* of *bemerken* is *bemerkt*.

According to [dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bemerken) the meaning is a little less specific than for *merken*.

*Bemerken* means just

> perceiving sth. / so.

and is therefore not limited to an emotional jugdement of the real-world observations.

**in short:**

*Bemerken* is perceiving something observable.

*Merken* is dealing with it emotionally.

Please consider [@Janka's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/74401/36196) regarding a flaw in both variants if it comes to being correct or not.

Comment: thank you for your answer!